# One XML multiple XSL stylesheets (XSLT) to one .FO to One PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, apache-fop, stylevision

I have created different stylesheets using Altova StyleVision for different pages for our website application. One XSLT would be for quotes and another for plans selected.

I am also new to XML and XSLT so it took some time to understand.

My question: I have One JSON file which gets converted to XML then to dynamically choose different sheets depending on the preferences of the user and combined them to produce a .FO file to PDF.

We decided to use Saxon and Apache FOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what your application architecture is (perhaps it's not even decided yet?) which makes this question rather hard to answer. The most obvious would be to write a Java servlet that accepts a request from the user, and based on the URL and/or parameters, invokes a transformation using Saxon's Java API and then sends the result in the HTTP response. Perhaps I'm missing some complexity that makes it more difficult than that?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Sorry for the delay in thanking you. We figured out a solution to use Saxon to FOP. We did what you stated to have a system that gets the request from the user based on parameters that are put into a JSON.